# Android Http GET Method Request

Tags: android, json, http-post, http-get

I have developed HTTP Post and Get method.Firstly Http post method clearly works and authentication was successful but second step I want to take data information what ı want to choose unfortunately Json object returns null.

Following Main Code:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login","userno"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept","application/json"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-type","x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));


        veri_string=post.httpPost(url, "GET", params, 2000);
        try {
            veri_json=new JSONObject(veri_string);





        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("HTTP POST CEVAP",""+veri_json);


        return null;
    }
```

My Post Class Code:

```
 try {

        if (method == "POST") {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeout1 = time;
            int timeout2 = time;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout1);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout2);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            veri =  httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            veri =  httpEntity.getContent();            
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                veri, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        veri.close();
        veri_string = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Hata " + e.toString());
             }

    return veri_string; // Aldığımız cevabın string halini geri dönüyoruz
```

MY web api url:http://ogrenci.izmir.edu.tr/api/ogrenciders

> {"Id":2602,"OgrenciNo":"","OgrenciAdiSoyadi":null,"OgretimYili":2014,"OgretimDonemi":1,"AldigiDersIdNo":0.0,"AldigiSube":null,"OgretimYiliAdi":"2014-2015","OgretimDonemiAdi":"Güz Dönemi","DersKodu":"CEN 431","DersAdi":"VERİ İLETİŞİMİ","Sinif":4,"SinifAdi":"4. sınıf","Vize1":0,"Vize2":0,"Vize3":0,"Vize4":0,"Vize5":0,"Vize6":0,"Vize7":0,"Vize8":0,"Vize9":0,"Vize10":0,"Final":0,"Butunleme":0,"EkSinav":0,"Vize1Adi":"Vize 
>   70","Vize2Adi":"Quiz 
>   64","Vize3Adi":"Assignments

And finally I take ERROR like that
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Asynctask doInBackground method you have to return what you're trying to get. In your case, you want the json string of

```
try {
    veri_json=new JSONObject(veri_string);
}
```

Currently you're returning null, so this variable is never passed back to the caller class.

Additionally, you'll want to return this variable in the "onPostExecute" method. So the doInBackground returns something (a String) and then the onPostExecute receives the string (its automatic since these are Override methods of Asynctask), and then the same onPostExecute method returns the result (the received String) to the caller class, usually with an interface.

Comment: Thank you for answering @TooManyEduardos I am a new developing in android I , as far as i understand I should variable (a string) in on postExecute and can you give me specific instance

Comment: well the problem you have is that at the end of the doInBackground you're returning null, which means you're not doing anything with the result. So it depends on what you want to do to on how to use this, but if you want to use the result of the doInBackground somewhere else, you need to return it to the caller class and thread, and since you're using Asynctask the easiest way to do that is using the onPostExecute

Comment: Try this website: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask

Comment: I look this website it is well for me but I think İn my code I have mistake  my schhol web site is wrong or in get method something wrong like that because I try all of possible but ı cant succeed @TooManyEduardos